# Child elements in hover cannot be selected

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm working on a fix for my current top navigation bar, the issue here is that the navbar sometimes has a lot of menus to choose from, this is depending of the permissions the logged user has, some users can only see 3 or 4 options while admins might see everything (around 16 menu options).

If the browser window is maximized, the menu can be seen perfectly, if the browser window start getting smaller, the menus are getting stacked depending of the size of the window. Some menus have submenus, and those submenus sometimes have even more submenus, so if there are like 2,3 or 4 levels of menus, the menus get out of the viewport and the user cannot see what the option is.

Here is a jsfiddle for my current top navigation bar menu:
https://jsfiddle.net/38qyt0gt/

And here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgzog0p0/8/) that uses a code snippet I took from Codepen and replaced some parts to match the design of the actual menu I have, the only problem is that this menu also has the same issue with the viewport and there is an issue with the child elements of some menus when you hover over the first level, the submenus show up, but you can't select them or hover them.

Here is a little [video](https://vimeo.com/243854317) showing off the issue of the new navigation bar.

I already tried fixing it by applying the next selector but it doesn't work either:

```css
#TopMenu_dropnav > ul > li:hover > ul{
  display: block;
}
```

Hope anybody can help

**EDIT**

Here is the CSS of the new menu bar

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 123;
  padding: 10px;
  font: 18px verdana;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
  display: none;
}

.logo a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#TopMenu_dropnav,
#TopMenu_dropnav ul,
#TopMenu_dropnav ul li,
#TopMenu_dropnav ul li a,
#TopMenu_dropnav #head-mobile {
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#TopMenu_dropnav:after,
#TopMenu_dropnav > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

#TopMenu_dropnav #head-mobile {
  display: none;
}

#TopMenu_dropnav {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #1976D2;
}

#TopMenu_dropnav > ul > li {
  float: left;
}

#TopMenu_dropnav > ul > li > a {
  padding: 17px;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ddd;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#TopMenu_dropnav > ul > li:hover > a,
#TopMenu_dropnav ul li.active a {
  color: #fff;
}

#TopMenu_dropnav > ul > li:hover,
#TopMenu_dropnav ul li.active:hover,
#TopMenu_dropnav ul li.active,
#TopMenu_dropnav ul li.has-sub.active:hover{
  background: #2196F3!important; 
  -webkit-transition: background .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: background .3s ease;
  transition: background .3s ease;
}

#TopMenu_dropnav > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

#TopMenu_dropnav > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #ddd;
  content: '';
}

#TopMenu_dropnav > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #ddd;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

#TopMenu_dropnav > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 23px;
  height: 0;
}

#TopMenu_dropnav ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

#TopMenu_dropnav ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  background: #333;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

#TopMenu_dropnav li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
}

#TopMenu_dropnav li:hover > ul > li {
  height: 35px;
}

#TopMenu_dropnav ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

#TopMenu_dropnav ul ul li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.15);
  padding: 11px 15px;
  width: 170px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ddd;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#TopMenu_dropnav ul ul li:last-child > a,
#TopMenu_dropnav ul ul li.last-item > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

#TopMenu_dropnav ul ul li:hover > a,
#TopMenu_dropnav ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

#TopMenu_dropnav ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #ddd;
  content: ''
}

#TopMenu_dropnav ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #ddd;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

#TopMenu_dropnav ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 17px;
  height: 0;
}

#TopMenu_dropnav ul ul li.has-sub:hover,
#TopMenu_dropnav ul li.has-sub ul li.has-sub ul li:hover {
  background: #363636;
}

#TopMenu_dropnav ul ul ul li.active a {
  border-left: 1px solid #333
}

#TopMenu_dropnav > ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a,
#TopMenu_dropnav > ul ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active> a {
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1000px) {
  nav {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 46px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  #TopMenu_dropnav ul {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #TopMenu_dropnav ul li {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #444;
  }
  #TopMenu_dropnav ul li:hover {
    background: #363636;
  }
  #TopMenu_dropnav ul ul li,
  #TopMenu_dropnav li:hover > ul > li {
    height: auto;
  }
  #TopMenu_dropnav ul li a,
  #TopMenu_dropnav ul ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  #TopMenu_dropnav > ul > li {
    float: none;
  }
  #TopMenu_dropnav ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 25px;
  }
  #TopMenu_dropnav ul ul li {
    background: #333!important;
  }
  #TopMenu_dropnav ul ul li:hover {
    background: #363636!important;
  }
  #TopMenu_dropnav ul ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 35px;
  }
  #TopMenu_dropnav ul ul li a {
    color: #ddd;
    background: none;
  }
  #TopMenu_dropnav ul ul li:hover > a,
  #TopMenu_dropnav ul ul li.active > a {
    color: #fff;
  }
  #TopMenu_dropnav ul ul,
  #TopMenu_dropnav ul ul ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
  }
  #TopMenu_dropnav > ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
  #TopMenu_dropnav > ul > li.has-sub > a:before,
  #TopMenu_dropnav ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
  #TopMenu_dropnav ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
    display: none;
  }
  #TopMenu_dropnav #head-mobile {
    display: block;
    padding: 23px;
    color: #ddd;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  .button {
    width: 55px;
    height: 46px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 12399994;
  }
  .button:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: 20px;
    display: block;
    height: 4px;
    width: 20px;
    border-top: 2px solid #dddddd;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  .button:before {
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    right: 20px;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #ddd;
    content: '';
  }
  .button.menu-opened:after {
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    top: 23px;
    border: 0;
    height: 2px;
    width: 19px;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  .button.menu-opened:before {
    top: 23px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 19px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  #TopMenu_dropnav .submenu-button {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    border-left: 1px solid #444;
    height: 46px;
    width: 46px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #TopMenu_dropnav .submenu-button.submenu-opened {
    background: #262626;
  }
  #TopMenu_dropnav ul ul .submenu-button {
    height: 34px;
    width: 34px;
  }
  #TopMenu_dropnav .submenu-button:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: 19px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
    background: #ddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #TopMenu_dropnav ul ul .submenu-button:after {
    top: 15px;
    right: 13px;
  }
  #TopMenu_dropnav .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
    background: #fff;
  }
  #TopMenu_dropnav .submenu-button:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 19px;
    right: 22px;
    display: block;
    width: 2px;
    height: 8px;
    background: #ddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #TopMenu_dropnav ul ul .submenu-button:before {
    top: 12px;
    right: 16px;
  }
  #TopMenu_dropnav .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before {
    display: none;
  }
  #TopMenu_dropnav ul ul ul li.active a {
    border-left: none;
  }
  #TopMenu_dropnav > ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a,
  #TopMenu_dropnav > ul ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a {
    border-top: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please put all relevant code in the question. If jsFiddle goes down your question will be unanswerable.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I put everything in jsfiddle because the code is a bit too large, and the post only allows 30,000 characters

Comment: Show your full codes

Comment: Why you are not use table tr td ? Its can be done with table than ul or ol element. And table can be set to horizontal overfow if childs more than width of table

Comment: @JoseAndresValenciaAcosta then please just show the relevant code to your current situation. You don't need to include all the fiddles.

Comment: `z-index: 9` on `#TopMenu_dropnav ul ul` will solve the stacking context issue demonstrated in the video. The responsive issue is difficult to demonstrate since the navigation collapses @ `max-width:1000px` anyway. There'll be no issue with character limits if you embed your code in the Code Snippet.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I added the CSS of the new menu, the other fiddle was just to give some background so everybody could understand the transition from the old to the new, where as the old one, doesn't have the hover issue and the new one does

Answer (score 0):

Add `onclick=""` to anything you wish iOS to recognise as an element with a hover. Try this :

```
<div onclick="">Click Me!</div>
```

Or could maybe use CSS media queries to change sizes depending on viewport,

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { 
  .your_class_here {
    /* css style goes here; */
  }
}
```